# DNS Error Page Not Found Using Cassini and IIS Local Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, webforms, cassini

I have an existing asp.net project that I'm attempting to move to a new development machine.  The issue I'm encountering is that even though the project builds without error I cannot preview the page in a browser.  Both IE and Chrome return a DNS Error Page Not Found.  Here's what I've done thus far after about two weeks of banging my head against the wall.

1. Edited local hosts file to
   uncomment the 127.0.0.1 localhost
   line (the :: line was already
   commented out as many blogs said it
   should be)
2. Attempted using IIS Local Development Server instead of Cassini
3. Disabled IPv6 (some articles I read suggested that it causes a conflict...I re-enabled it after it failed to remedy my issue)
4. Reinstalled .NET 4.0
5. Recopied
   a fresh image of the VS from my
   other machine where it runs
   correctly
6. Scoured Stackoverflow
   and MSDN for other possible
   solutions

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I should try?

PS - I'm using a Windows 7 machine

UPDATE:
I recopied the original project from the old machine to the new machine.  The project built with errors but Cassini loaded the default.aspx page successfully.  However, when I then fixed the reference to missing DLLs that are part of the solution the problem reoccurred.  And interestingly when I then removed the offending references it still did not work.  Could something in the referenced DLLs be causing the main project to break and not load correctly? I examined the source code (mostly logic for manipulating data) and don't see anything that would necessarily cause default.aspx not to load.